# Why is there an undefined variable when I am trying to invoke csh

Tags: csh

I am trying to invoke csh from the terminal using:

```
$csh
SDB: Undefined variable.
```

I never faced this before and I do not really understand what is meant by SDB here and how is it an undefined variable? Any ideas?

Comment: Try starting as `csh -V` to see what is being run. As the error says, you have an undefined variable *somewhere*, but we don't have access to your system and can't tell you where that is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SolarSoft.

Check if your Solarsoft Database (SSWDB) environment is set in upper case as SDB and not sdb

Comment: Hi, Yes. I figured out it was a solar soft issue. There was no such thing in my .cshrc before but adding a setenv SDB "" to it and sourcing csh again helped eliminate the issue. Thanks :)